Replacing jockey wheels on Shimano Deore rear derailleur
I have a hybrid-style bike with the following parts:
• Shimano 7-speed rapid-fire shifters
• Shimano Altus FC-M311 crank set 48/38/28
• Shimano Deore RD-M592 rear derailleur
• Shimano MF-TZ500 rear freewheel 14-34
• SRAM PC870 chain
This combination has worked fine for the few years I've had the bike. However, one of the jockey wheels on the rear derailleur is damaged and I need to replace it.
These (https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B004T0GGTQ) appear to be the correct replacement jockey wheels for the derailleur, but I noticed they're mentioned as being for 10-speed drivetrains, whereas mine is only 7-speed.
Could anyone confirm that these replacement wheels will be compatible with the other parts on my bike?

I actually recommend a different approach. Don't buy official Shimano jockey wheels, buy ones from a third party such as BBB instead (I would have recommended Tacx in the past, but they don't seem to be available anymore), for the correct chain width you have.
Shimano's jockey wheels for older drivetrains have a problem: they used a wobbly "Centeron" pulley as the upper pulley. The theory probably was that it allowed users to pre-shift (shifting while not pedaling, then starting to pedal to finalize the shift), but at the same time made the shifting less precise. This used to work up to 8/9 speeds or so, but with the more modern drivetrains such as 11-speed, the requirements of precision are so big that Shimano had to ditch Centeron pulleys.
Centeron pulleys are not for your benefit. You will enjoy more precise shifting with 7/8 speed drivetrains as well, if you ditch the Centeron pulley and go with a non-wobbly pulley for the upper pulley was well.
Third-party manufacturers like BBB and Tacx don't bother with the wobbly Centeron pulleys, but have precise pulleys for both the upper and lower pulley.

Interesting about the wobbly pulley. The original one on the RD-M592 was indeed a wobbly one, really annoyed me. The new ones (like the linked part) don't appear to wobble anymore, but rather have an elongated bush so the wheel can slide sideways along it a millimetre or so. That seems to work much better.

Tacx discontinued manufacturing pulley wheels a long time ago after being acquired by Wahoo.

Tacx is part of Garmin not Wahoo isn't it?

@PaulSuart Yes, sorry, by Garmin. The sideline productions were axed by the new owners.

In my experience, a jockey wheel works fine as long as it fits.  So the tooth count needs to be the same or less.  You may get away with one-over but a derailleur that takes an 11 tooth won't take a 17 tooth.
Chain is different external widths, whereas the internal width is fairly consistent.
Personally I like cheap Aliexpress jockey wheels - with a bushing if they're for a MTB or wet bike, and with bearings if they're for my good dry-weather bike.

With a bushing for MTB and bearings for dry weather? Why? I had repeated problems with bushings in Shimano pulley wheels getting dirt on an off-road bike (caused horrible screaks) until I replaced them with 3rd party ones with sealed ball bearings.

@VladimirFГероямслава I like the bearing ones with lanolin lube for dry rides, but they don't survive a lot of wet rides.  Bushing ones seem to be basically indestructable, at least until there's several millimetres slogged out in the middle of the wheel.

@VladimirFГероямслава  Further - the bearings definitely have a hard stop on their life compared to a bushing which steadily gets sloppier as it wears out.    This morning my upper jockey bearing wedged up hard and wouldn't turn, so I opened it on the road side, lost all the bearing balls, and reassembled.  It worked fine to get to work, and surprisingly shifted fine.  I think there is something in the idea of centeron, specially on slightly inaccurate shifting systems

The official replacement reference for the RD-M592 can be found on the exploded view, they have the following reference: Y-5VM 98070. There are more than probably other references as well that can work, that being said, ultimately, the only metrics that matter are the thickness of the wheel assembly, and the number of teeth.
Note also that the RD-M592 is officially a 9-speed rear derailleur (same pull ratio between 7 and 9 speed, so no problem). The inside width of a 7-speed chain is 0.2mm wider than a 9-speed one (same inside width between 9 and 12 speed), so it's not optimum, but that goes in the right direction.

I have an RD-M592-SGS on my hybrid and recently had to replace the pulleys.
Ended up buying the RD-5700 pully set (Y5XH98120) to replace them as that's what the LBS had in stock and was stated as compatible. Looks like the same thing as you link too.
They work well, if not better than the original pulleys. I put a little bit of lube on the bushes when assembling.
Granted mine is set up for a 9 speed, but that shouldn't make any difference.

Given the theoretical match, this post pretty much gives the definite answer.

I use the 5700* (Y5XH98120) pulley wheels on a 9sp deraileur on a 8sp bike with no issues (even though my RD-M3100 is not even in the compatibility list). Looking at shimanos exploded views the 5700 seem to fit your deraileur since your pulleys are listed as identical to the m530 pulley wheels and this series is listed as compatible for the 5700.
The width of the 5700 pulley wheels between the metal covers is approximately 8.2mm if you want to make a measurement. Both use m5 bolts and are 11 tooth, so hard to imagine a non-fit if the original width is the same.
Shimano use the same pulley for some 8, 9 and 10-speed systems so I would not worry about that. The specs also indicate that the 5700 should match, but I give no promises.
https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/service-upgradeparts/105-5800/WP-Y5XH98120.html
*)shimano lists them as 5701(can't find 5700), but with the same part number Y5XH98120
